# Winter camping in Western Europe sleeping bag question

Tags: sleeping-bags, europe, car-camping, spain, portugal

I will be car camping in Western Europe (Portugal & Spain) from Nov. 14-Dec. 22nd this year. I will be camping in a wide range of environments, ranging from the mountainous Asturias Province of Northern Spain to coastal Mediterranean areas like Cadiz. I am looking for a new sleeping bag that will suit this type of excursion.

Does anyone have recommendations on what temperature rating of sleeping bag would be good for this area at this time of year?

Comment: In what type of elevation/climate will you be camping? Beach? High mountains? The answers could vary depending on elevation and climate. Also, product reviews are off-topic as they require opinion-based answers.

Comment: Spain and Portugal are southern Europe, for this question it would matter a lot because it doesn't get nearly as cold there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on where you are camping I would recommend a three or four season synthetic sleeping bag.

Synthetic bags are generally cheaper and bulkier than down bags for an equivalent warmth. As you are car camping the additional bulk isn't that important.

Most of Spain has night temperatures between 5-0 C this time of year so a three season bag should be fine. Sleeping bags generally have a comfort temperature rating (and sometimes an extreme temperature rating too). I would look for a bag with a comfort temp of about 0 C or a bit lower. Depending on your preference you may even get away with a two season bag if you don't mind wearing extra clothes/being cold.

If you are in the mountains the temperature will be somewhat colder and you may need a four season bag. Have a look at the expected night temperatures for the places you are going to.